# How do I sync my Skyrim achievements with Steam if I use SKSE?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam, achievements

In my other question, I asked if I could get the Steam overlay in Skyrim if I use the SKSE .exe file. (Reference Question: [How can I get the Steam overlay on Skyrim, if I am using the SKSE.exe to launch the game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49564/how-can-i-get-the-steam-overlay-on-skyrim-if-i-am-using-the-skse-exe-to-launch))

I would like to sync my Skyrim achievements with Steam, even though I am using the SKSE .exe through a "non-steam game" (details are at the other question).

I know this is beginning to get complicated. I hope you can understand what I mean! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achievements are only granted the moment you meet the criteria, they are not stored in the save, so you can't sync them. You can use the [Steam Achievement Manager](http://gib.me/sam/) to give yourself any achievements you want.

Comment: I think discussion of these types of tools isn't appropriate

Comment: Why would it be? Achievements aren't a particularly hot moral topic.

Comment: It's perhaps appropriate isn't the right word.
What I mean is that use of tools like SAM are considered by some to be like hacking/cracking which isn't encouraged on this site. But I agree SAM isn't really illegal.

Comment: I actually liked this suggestion.

Comment: turns out this actually answers both this question and my next, which was why aren't they syncing. It's because I only get the achievement when it is achieved. Thanks for your help!

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Answer (score 7):

I renamed `skse_loader.exe` to `SkyrimLauncher.exe` and it works like a charm.
If I started the game using `skse_loader.exe` directly, I would not get the Steam overlay or the achievements.

Be sure to make a backup of the original launcher as you need it to synchronize mods (just rename it when you want to sync)

Answer (score 4):

When you run `skse_loader.exe`, SKSE does some magic behind the scenes to launch Skyrim in such a way that Steam thinks you're playing Skyrim normally.

You shouldn't have to do anything to get credit for your achievements and play time, even if you're using the "non-Steam game" method to run SKSE.

(Confirmed through my [own experience using SKSE](http://steamcommunity.com/id/adversity/stats/TheElderScrollsVSkyrim) and earning achievements)

Comment: I can second this. Been using skse_loader.exe since it came out with Steam overlay and achievements.

Comment: but how? I am only running it as a third party game in order to launch through SKSE...

Comment: turns out doesn't matter. they don't sync.